Удалить данные из одного массива, не имеющиеся в другом массиве
Есть 2 массива:
let a = [
['A'; 1], ['B', 2], ['D', 2]
];

let b = [
['A'; 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 2], ['D', 5], ['E', 7]
];

Необходимо удалить из массива b данные ['C', 2] и ['E', 7], то есть те, которых нет в массиве A. Как это сделать?

т.е. две подзадачи - найти , и удалить. Какая не получается?

Почему [d,5] должно остаться?


Необходимо удалить из массива b данные ['C', 2] и ['E', 7], то есть те, которых нет в массиве A. Как это сделать?

Например вот так...


const a = [
  ['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['D', 2]
];

let b = [
  ['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 2], ['D', 5], ['E', 7]
];
b = b.filter(([b1, b2]) => a.some(([a1, a2]) => a1 === b1 && a2 === b2))
console.log(b)




Уважаемый Ksa, спасибо огромное!
Очень помогли. Тот пример, когда потратил двое суток, а ответ был в одной строке.

еще вариант


let a = [
  ['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['D', 2]
];

let b = [
  ['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 2], ['D', 5], ['E', 7]
];

//set из 1го массива
const setA = new Set(a.map(item => `${item[0]}-${item[1]}`));

let filteredB = b.filter(item => setA.has(`${item[0]}-${item[1]}`));

console.log(filteredB);



